# How to group the Stackpanel list and adjust the height of the items dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a stackpanel which dynamically displays a list of small list box items. say eg. 5 to 50. Currently the stack panel doesnt display all 50. It displays only until if the size is 30 for example.

How can dynamically adjust the height so that all fits in the screen?
How to add a group in order of 4 for example and write a number on it for the group ( like 4,8,12).?

I have tried to set the height parameter of the item but it didnt help

[image: StackPanel from Snoop]
[image: Xaml]

Comment: Post the xaml. it will be more helpfull

Comment: thanks.. I added the xaml. I used custom height converter to do it. But Now I am unable to change the order of stackpanel containing textblock and border.